# output will not format correctly

Tags: powershell

I am having some problems writing to a text file with powershell using the correct format.  I am pulling some windows event logs and saving the output to a text file.  When I issue the following 2 commands

```
$event = get-winevent -filterhashtable @{logname='ForwardedEvents'; id=4688} 

$event | format-list >> C:\scripts\file01.txt
```

I get something like this saved to the text file with a bunch of white space and the line broken up because it is too long:

```
               New Process Name:    
           C:\Windows\System32\SearchFilterHost.exe
```

Is there anyway to make the output look like this instead:

```
New Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\SearchFilterHost.exe
```

thanks

Comment: You could output the message, as is: `$evt.Message >> C:\scripts\file01.txt`

Comment: Awesome that worked!!!

Comment: Glad to help, posted a proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in the message content of the event, don't pipe the entire event object through `Format-List` - output the `Message` property directly instead:

```
$evt.Message >> C:\scripts\file01.txt
```